# How to build a facebook-like fast search by starting of words?

Tags: search, key-value, nosql

I have to build a search textbox in a web page similar to facebook search box. Client side there will be ajax calls. The user need to search into around 300.000 elements that have a description of a few words or an alphanumeric code. When user enters the beginning of a word, a call is made to the server which return best match based on the starting of any word or code but also suggest first the elements most recently by the user, then by the group the user belongs to and finally from the entire set. Result can be limited to 10-20 items.

How can I build a fast search by key with the value just the description of the element? We use SQL server but any other DB could be OK.

Comment: At the moment I have in mind a key-value structure that I populate as follow: at beginning for each element I split all words in the description and  every word will point to a list of element. When a user selects an element  for using it inside the app, I will insert a key composed by userid and every word of description plus group id and every word of description

Comment: I bet I had asked how much is 1 + 1, I'd have received 100 answers..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation at the time was very complex to summarise here but I came across recently to UI-select that solve the front end problem nicely and it's very good component if you are using Angular
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select

then backend you can put whatever you have (I did with Redis)